# How to check div before and after specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a class called `.options.selected`. I wanted to see if I am able to select the `.line` that's before it and after using jQuery?

```
<div class="options-label">Price:</div>
<div class="options first">$0 - $100</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="options">$100 - $200</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="options">$200</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="options selected all">All</div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `.prev()` for previous div and `.next()` for next one:

```
 var prevDiv = $('.options.selected').prev('.line'),
        nextDiv = $('.options.selected').next('.line');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.options.selected').parent().prev('.line');
$('.options.selected').parent().next('.line');
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
//Before:
$('.options.selected').parent().prev('.line');

//After:
$('.options.selected').parent().next('.line');
```

Or:

```
//Before:
$('.options.selected').prev('.line');

//After:
$('.options.selected').next('.line');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var prev = $('.options.selected').prev('.line');
  var next = $('.options.selected').next('.line');

});
```

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/j0bvso7p/1/)